# How would I make a dictionary that can store user input in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know how I would be able to make a dictionary that can store multiple user input and print them out if requested. I have tried it with this code but I guess I am wrong because it's not working:

```
def new_questions():
new_question = {}
while new_question:
    newly_added_question = raw_input('Please type the question:')
    newly_added_question_ans1 = raw_input('Please type the CORRECT answer:')
    newly_added_question_ans2 = raw_input('Please type an incorrect answer:')
    newly_added_question_ans3 = raw_input('Please type an incorrect answer:')
    new_question[newly_added_question] = newly_added_question_ans1
    new_question[newly_added_question] = newly_added_question_ans2
    new_question[newly_added_question] = newly_added_question_ans3
```

Comment: A dictionary can only store one value per key (although that value can be a container, like a list or another dictionary); you're overwriting previous entries. Also note you should provide a [mcve] to illustrate what *"not working"* actually means.

Comment: You must store a collections of strings, e.g. a list or a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making list of all answers and store it as:

```
new_question[newly_added_question] = [newly_added_question_ans1, newly_added_question_ans2, newly_added_question_ans3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary to store each value of the `new question` dictionary, as follows:

```
from pprint import pprint    

def new_questions():
    new_question = True

    questions = {}
    while new_question:
        question = raw_input('Please type the question:')
        ans1 = raw_input('Please type the CORRECT answer:')
        ans2 = raw_input('Please type an incorrect answer:')
        ans3 = raw_input('Please type an incorrect answer:')

        answers = {
            'correct': ans1,
            'incorrect_1': ans2,
            'incorrect_2': ans3
        }

        questions[question] = answers

        next_question = raw_input('\nAnother question? (Y/N): ')

        if next_question.lower() == 'n':
            new_question = False

    pprint(questions)

new_questions()
```

---

Sample Output:

```
Please type the question:How many e's in eternity?
Please type the CORRECT answer:2
Please type an incorrect answer:3
Please type an incorrect answer:42

Another question? (Y/N): y
Please type the question:Is this real?
Please type the CORRECT answer:Yes.
Please type an incorrect answer:No.
Please type an incorrect answer:Maybe?
Another question? (Y/N): n
{"How many e's in eternity?": {'correct': '2',
                               'incorrect_1': '3',
                               'incorrect_2': '42'},
 'Is this real?': {'correct': 'Yes.',
                   'incorrect_1': 'No.',
                   'incorrect_2': 'Maybe?'}}
```

You can access each question's answers as `questions[question]['correct']`, `questions[question]['incorrect_1']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you are overriding the value of the key in the dictionary, whenever you assign a new answer to the question.

Try some container to store the values of your key. i.e To hold answers to your questions in the dictionary you can use list as a container. see example below.

```
result = {}  #Empty dictionary

def new_question(result):
  question = input("Enter the question: ")
  ans1 = input("Enter the Correct answer ")
  ans2 = input("Enter the Incorrect answer ")
  ans3 = input("Enter the another Incorrect answer ")
  answers = [ans1,ans2,ans3]  #storing answers in a list
  result[question] = answers  #setting answers to question

new_question(result) #add questions and answers by calling this fuction, call this in a loop if multiple questions
print(result) # print all the questions and answers
```

NOTE: if you have defined number of options for answers then you can add a loop for user input as well.